# Why web frameworks build pages from templates rather than logical blocks?

Tags: python, django, templates, web-frameworks, zope

I am new to web frameworks. I always imagined that they'll be working as building a page  from a **logical blocks** of the page (layout, header, menu, content, footer, etc.). Then they'll set up each logical block (content & look).

I had a brief look at following frameworks:

- Django
- Web2py
- Zope
- CherryPy

(I didn't make CubicWeb working.)

None of them seems to be working the way I imagined. Instead they rely on system of **templates** in whose I have to manually construct all trivial elements of a page.

Obviously there have to be some good reasons behind the proven way, but I don't see them.

Why the frameworks do not build pages from logical blocks?
Is there some (python) framework which works the way I expected?

Comment: But templates can be structured to provide logical blocks.. Zope uses viewlets, for example, which provide logical snippets of HTML output based on context and the request, but (can) use templates to produce that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question describes a content management system rather than a webframework which are meant for much more than just rendering templates. E.g. you can use a webframework to build a cms that renders content types as blocks, although you would probably be wasting your time reinventing the wheel.

An example of a block rendering CMS for Django, [FeinCMS](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/)

Comment: Yeah, had to think of FeinCMS's [content types](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/contenttypes.html#bundled-content-types) too.
Though all [popular cms](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/)  will have similar features.